# Systemd service to run script at boot under a specified user account

Tags: 15.04, systemd

I'm very new to systemd and I'm trying to set up a little startup script for a Teamspeak server and I'm having some trouble getting it to actually start up.

Some info:

- The Teamspeak server runs under its own user account, named `ts3`.
- The server files are located in `/home/teamspeak3-server/`
- Inside that directory is a shell script which allows you to start/stop/restart the server (this comes bundled with the software).  e.g. `ts3server_startscript.sh start`

I created a new service in `/lib/systemd/system`, here are its contents:

```
[Unit]
Description=TeamSpeak 3 Server Startup Service
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=simple
User=ts3
ExecStart=/bin/bash /home/ts3/teamspeak3-server/ts3server_startscript.sh start

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

When I start it:

```
$ systemctl start teamspeak3
==== AUTHENTICATING FOR org.freedesktop.systemd1.manage-units ===
Authentication is required to manage system services or units.
Authenticating as: bob,,, (bob)
Password:
==== AUTHENTICATION COMPLETE ===
```

Appears to succeed, but the server does not start up.  I have tried to reboot, just in case it's not firing off because of `After=network.target`.. but it still doesn't want to come up.

Any idea what I am missing here?

**EDIT:** Got it working but forgot how.. adding my Systemd script here:

```
[Unit]
Description=TeamSpeak 3 Server Startup Service
Wants=network-online.target
After=network.target network-online.target

[Service]
Type=forking
User=ts3
ExecStart=/bin/sh /home/ts3/teamspeak3-server/ts3server_startscript.sh start
PIDFile=/home/ts3/teamspeak3-server/ts3server.pid

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Comment: Im also getting similar error.
How did you solved?

Comment: @itsazzad I don't remember if there was anything special I had to do to get this working, but I've had it up and running fine now for 3 months.  I edited my main post with my current (working) systemd script.   Just change your `ExecStart` and `PIDFile` lines to point to where you have Teamspeak installed, then execute `systemctl daemon-reload`.. and then run `systemctl enable teamspeak3.service` or whatever you called it to make it start on boot.